# IIS express crashes after successfully debugged and build

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, iis-express

I am running my mvc project in visual studio 2013 no errors comes in debugging and all projects build up successfully. after it when visual studio run the project and launch IIS express process it got crashes with following error which comes in result window.

> The program '[13280] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1073740771
>   (0xc000041d). The program '[13280] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has
>   exited with code 0 (0x0).

I also re install visual studio reset its all settings problem still exist.

I also check whether iis is working ok? I deployed the websites on iis and they are working fine, Only the websites which i run from visual studio did not work and gives upper mention error message.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem myself... I make a couple of changes which solved my problem, Steps are as follows....

1. Uninstall IIS 
   1.1. Go to control panel-> Programs and features -> Turn Windows Features On or Off.
   1.2 De-select Internet Information Services and Internet Information Services Hostable Web Core.
   1.3 Restart the system.
   1.4 Go to My Documents and delete folder "IISExpress".

   2. Install IIS again
      2.1. Go to control panel-> Programs and features -> Turn Windows Features On or Off.
      2.2 select Internet Information Services and Internet Information Services Hostable Web Core.
      2.3 Restart the system.
      this solved the problem.

Comment: I really wished this worked all the time.. problem just keeps coming back