# IIS Express not running in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I am developing a chat application using ASP.NET Core MVC architecture.

Initially, the project worked well and could run on IIS Express. but later I found that now the IDE is not working; the project cannot run IIS Express.

I am getting the following error as an alert message as well as in the output console when trying to run my application from Visual Studio:

> Error: The program '[18268] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Screenshot of the alert message in the IDE: [image: Click here to view]

After a while, I restarted the project and when I run the project again, I got the following error again:

? Error: The program '[17512] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I am confused what is wrong with my project or IDE. Can somebody please help me to resolve this?

I checked [Error running IIS-Express in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62745345/error-running-iis-express-in-visual-studio) and [IIS express crashes after successfully debugged and build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29533530/iis-express-crashes-after-successfully-debugged-and-build) but they are very old posts and I could not find an answer to my problem.

Comment: If you delete the hidden .vs folder from Solution, can it show normally?

Comment: @Karney. Thank you for the support. but could not see such a folder. I noticed in some posts what you said is mentioned as an accepted answer. but I could not find any hidden folder when viewing from visual studio or file explorer.

Comment: Please refer to this link open the visible folder. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/view-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-10-97fbc472-c603-9d90-91d0-1166d1d9f4b5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873126/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Check your solution folder for a hidden ".vs" folder.
2. In Visual Studio, right click on the web project, chose properties and then navigated to the "web" tab. From there I changed the Project URL to another port number. For example, if it was http://localhost... -  Changed it to  http://localhost:43567.

[image]

3. If your machine is 64bit, please go to Tools-> options -> projects and solutions:

[image]